# Moqui entity field-type-options boolean

Tags: moqui

I want to create a Entity in which there is a field of type Boolean. But according to XSD for entity-defintion in Moqui type of boolean is not defined. Is there a way to create a Boolean field in Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, all you have to do is add this property inside tag `<database-list>` in `MoquiDefaultConf.xml` .

```xml
<dictionary-type type="boolean" java-type="java.lang.Boolean" default-sql-type="BOOLEAN"/>
```

I am using PostgreSQL maybe its different in other database systems.

```xml
<dictionary-type type="boolean" java-type="java.lang.Boolean" default-sql-type="BOOLEAN"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no consistent boolean data type across different databases so to remain relational database agnostic Moqui uses a single character column with the `text-indicator` entity field type. The convention in Moqui Framework and the business artifacts in Moqui ecosystem is to use `Y` for yes/true and `N` for no/false.